# Disable movable Gmap

Tags: google-maps

is it possible to disable the move inside of a google mal (v3) for the time i drag a marker?
I don't want to use i.e. the static map. I need the generall function of movement, but for the moment I drag a marker, the map should not move.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Markers have [dragstart and dragend events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker). On `dragstart`, disable the "movement" functionality on the Map by setting various [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) to `false`, like `draggable`, `scrollwheel`, etc. On `dragend`, set the MapOptions back to `true`.

Here is a function you can use to disable or enable map movement based on a boolean. It assumes your Map variable is `map`.

```
function disableMovement(disable) {
    var mapOptions;
    if (disable) {
        mapOptions = {
            draggable: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            zoomControl: false
        };
    } else {
        mapOptions = {
            draggable: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
            zoomControl: true
        };
    }
    map.setOptions(mapOptions);
}
```

And then you use this in your events like this (`marker` is your Marker variable):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    disableMovement(true);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    disableMovement(false);
});
```

Comment: Ok - but which is the attribute for disable the movement of a map?

Comment: @Thomas1703 It's really a combination of MapOptions. Setting `draggable` to `false`, for example, disables panning. Setting `scrollwheel` to `false` disables use of the mouse's scrollwheel to zoom. `disableDoubleClickZoom` makes it so the user can't double-click the mouse to zoom, so set that to `true`. And for completeness, disable `zoomControl` by setting it to `false` so the zoom controls on the map are hidden. All of these together should restrict the user from moving the map. On draggend, set all of these attributes back to their defaults. Read the docs to know what MapOptions to set.

Comment: @Thomas1703 I updated my answer with some example code using setOptions method.

Answer (score 3):

gmap.setOptions({'scrollwheel': false});